# Sorting each column and getting their corresponding key IDs in the first row for the bottom 2 values

Tags: text-processing, sort

This is my working file. (Column number and Row number are not known)

```
key_ID  col_1 col_2 col_3
AA      1     1     1
BB      56    2     7
CC      89    5     2
DD      7     77    7
```

I want to sort each column for the bottom 2 values so to find their corresponding `key_ID`  from the first column.

Desired Output be like

```
col_1  col_2 col_3
AA     AA     AA
DD     BB     CC
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and give us some more detail please? Why does the 1st column of your output have `AA` and then `DD`? The top two values for `col_1` are `89` for `CC` and `56` for `BB`, so shouldn't the output have `CC` on the first line and `BB` on the second? Are you looking for the lowest two values in each column?

Comment: @terdon My apology. I am looking for lowest two values in each column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pure `bash`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

DATA=/path/to/input_data
COL_NUMS=$(head -1 $DATA | wc -w)

FILES=''
for i in $(seq 2 $COL_NUMS)
do
  FILE=$(mktemp)     
  echo col_$((i-1)) > $FILE
  cut -f1,$i -d' ' <(tail -n +2 $DATA | tr -s ' ') | 
        sort -k2 -g | head -2 | cut -f1 -d' ' >> $FILE

  FILES="$FILES $FILE"
done

paste $FILES
rm $FILES
```

Output:

```
col_1   col_2   col_3
AA      AA      AA
DD      BB      CC
```

---

What it does is looking at your columns and their labels, one by one and separately, for example `labels,col1` , then `labels,col2` and so on.

```
for i in $(seq 2 $COL_NUMS)
do
  ...
  cut -f1,$i -d' ' <(tail -n +2 $DATA | tr -s ' ')
```

Then it sorts and finds labels with the two lowest value in each group and puts them into a temp file.

```
FILE=$(mktemp)
...
sort -k2 -g | head -2 | cut -f1 -d' ' >> $FILE
```

While doing this we create a list of all these files.

```
FILES="$FILES $FILE"
```

So now we have a bunch of temp files containing the desired list and we should put them together using `paste` command and remove those temporary files:

```
paste $FILES
rm $FILES
```

Comment: Thanks!  Actually I am stuck in a middle of a script where it produces a file (Like the input file that is mentioned in the Question). The next thing I want to do is mentioned in the Question. So I don't know how many columns are there and it will be manual and impractical if I check the input  file every time for column numbers.

Comment: @Mr.206 Updated, you don't have to input the number of columns anymore.

Comment: It would be also great if $1 is replaced with input file.

Comment: I encountered a problem regarding exponential numbers. If there is scientific notation in the column values then sorting is not done correctly.

Comment: @Mr.206 Updated, I hope it works fine know... If it didn't ask a new question about sorting and inform us how your data looks like.

Comment: Hey, I solved the issue by introducing sort -g but Don't -g and -n conflict with each other?
In my case it is throwing an error like `-gn is not compatible` . 
Using only  `sort -k2 -g` is doing the work.

Comment: That's right... I added the `-g` and forgot to remove `-n` ;)

Comment: Very nice +1. I think when `do` is on new line you can omit `;` at end of `for` command.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks :) That's correct...

Comment: It would really great If you add some explanations. Thanks :)

Comment: @Mr.206 Done...

Answer (score 3):

Use `csvsql` from [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
paste \
<(csvsql -d ' ' -S  --query "select key_ID as "col_1" from file order by col_1 limit 2" file) \
<(csvsql -d ' ' -S  --query "select key_ID as "col_2" from file order by col_2 limit 2" file) \
<(csvsql -d ' ' -S  --query "select key_ID as "col_3" from file order by col_3 limit 2" file)
```

Output:

```
col_1   col_2   col_3
AA      AA      AA
DD      BB      CC
```

You should be able to install `csvkit` via `pip`:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
sudo pip install csvkit
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the Question, the column numbers are not fixed.

Comment: I see ... I'll try to fix

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea to my answer using `csvsql`, but using `paste`, `sort` and `awk`:

```
paste \
 <(tail -n+2 file | sort -k2n | awk 'BEGIN{print "col_1"} NR<3{print $1}') \
 <(tail -n+2 file | sort -k3n | awk 'BEGIN{print "col_2"} NR<3{print $1}') \
 <(tail -n+2 file | sort -k4n | awk 'BEGIN{print "col_3"} NR<3{print $1}')
```

Output:

```
col_1   col_2   col_3
AA      AA      AA
DD      BB      CC
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the Question, the column numbers are not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Not a `bash` solution, but in a SQL this can be done quite easily:

First, create the table:

```
create table working (key_ID char(2), col_1 integer, col_2 integer, col_3 integer);
insert into working values ("AA", 1,1,1), ("BB", 56, 2,7), ("CC", 89,5,2), ("DD", 7, 77, 7);
```

Now create three derived tables with the first and second values, add a row number to each, and join them on the row number:

```
set @row_num1 = 0;
set @row_num2 = 0;
set @row_num3 = 0;
select col1.key_ID as col_1, col2.key_ID as col_2, col3.key_ID as col_3 from 
    (select (@row_num1 := @row_num1 + 1 ) as num,key_ID, col_1 from working order by col_1 limit 2) as col1
        join (select (@row_num2 := @row_num2 + 1 ) as num,key_ID, col_2 from working order by col_2 limit 2) as col2 on col1.num = col2.num
        join (select (@row_num3 := @row_num3 + 1 ) as num,key_ID, col_3 from working order by col_3 limit 2) as col3 on col1.num = col3.num
```

gives

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| AA    | AA    | AA    |
| DD    | BB    | CC    |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want a bash solution in this case.

Comment: This requires installing and setting up a whole DB instance just to parse a single text file. Seems like overkill...

Comment: @terdon worse, it requires a whole Ubuntu system to be installed! That is, if you don't happen to have one lying around, of course. ;-D

Comment: Heh, true, true. Seriously though, setting up a database to parse a single file does seem needlessly complex. Most users won't have a DB lying around that they could just add a table to.

Comment: I'm wondering if `sqlite3` isn't installed by default on a Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score -1):

tail -n +2 gives you all but the heading row

sort -k2 -n sorts on the 2nd column - repeat this with -k3 and -k4 for the other columns

head -n 2 gives you the top 2 rows

```
tail -n +2 test | sort -k2 -n | head -n 2
```

Then store the output however you need it.

Comment: This isn't what the question asks for. Please see the desired output in the OP. The values need to be changed to the IDs in the 1st column.

Comment: Best of luck...